# Does metadata tell what shooting mode I used. Like continuous, one shot, timer, etc

Tags: continuous-drive

I used my camera in continuous mode and timer mode. I want to be able to tell which ones were from timer and which ones were in continuous. Is there a way to see that?

Comment: What software and camera are you using. I can see that info using digikam and my 5d Mark ii but what other cameras save might vary.

Comment: It depends on your camera and possibly what firmware version you are running or even a third party firmware such as Magic Lantern.

Comment: Hi, please specify what camera you are using. So far, this is a bad question.

Answer (score 1):

In the pictures from my EOS 70D, software (exiftool) shows a `Drive Mode` EXIF data which is coherent with the way the picture was taken:

- `Continuous` for pictures extracted from a burst (another application reports `Continuous, low`),
- `Timer` for a picture taken with a time (but it doesn't tell how long was the timer)

In practice the most comprehensive source of EXIF data for all brands of cameras is the [ExifTool documentation](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/index.html). It appears that the `Drive Mode` above is actually a compound of `Timer` and `ContinuousMode` fields in Canon cameras.

Comment: I found the same. Or more exact the Drive Mode can have several values for 'continuous, high', 'continuous, low', 'single' etc... see https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Canon.html#CameraSettings The Issue I have is that the SequenceNumber is always 0 and I'm unable to tell if this is still the same sequence or a new sequence has started..